Predicting Target Variable in Time Series Data from Multiple Experiments Using Statistical Models
I am working on a project where I aim to predict a specific target variable using time series panel data collected from multiple experiments conducted on the same equipment. The challenge involves using various features recorded during these experiments to forecast the target outcome.
Data Description:

Total Time Series: 19 (from 19 different experiments on the same machine)
Data Points per Series: ~800
Data Point Frequency: 100ms
Features per Data Point: 72 real-valued features
Target Variable: A specific measurable real-valued outcome

Data Distribution:

Training Data: Concatenation of 13 time series
Validation Data: Concatenation of 3 time series
Test Data: Concatenation of 3 time series

Current Approaches and Results:
My initial attempt involved using a VARIMA(X) model with principal components of the concatenated training data. However, I encountered difficulties in applying this model for prediction/regression as there seems to be no option to input validation/test data in the prediction step directly, other than using it as exogenous variables.
I have achieved good results with the same dataset using machine learning models like Long Short-Term Memory (LSTM) networks and Temporal Fusion Transformers (TFT). I have also looked into using multivariate adaptive regression splines (MARS) with additional lagged features.
Goals:

Model Training: To train a model effectively using all/most available features on the training dataset.
Prediction/Regression: To predict/regress the target variable accurately across the entire length of validation and test data series, where the model is provided with all features except the target.

General Questions:

What classic statistical modeling techniques or adjustments would you recommend for forecasting/regression in this type of time series data?
Is it feasible at all to predict/regress the target variable with VARIMA(X), considering the challenges mentioned?

Additional Information:
Given the success with LSTM and TFT models, I am now looking to contrast these with more traditional statistical methods. Insights related to improving or adapting statistical models for this type of time series forecasting would be greatly appreciated.
